# how to extract number beside specific string in a cell?

Tags: r, text-extraction

I would like to extract number information in cells which is located beside specific string. My data looks like this.

```
    item             stock
PRE 24GUSSETX4SX15G   200
PLS 12KLRX10SX15G     200
ADU 24SBX200ML        200
NIS 18BNDX40SX11G     200
REF 500GX12BTL        200
```

i want to extract the numbers which located besides string 'GUSSET','KLR','SB','BND' and 'BTL'. I want to use this number to do multiplication with the stock. For example like this.

```
            item         stock    pcs    total
    PRE 24GUSSETX4SX15G   200      24    4800
    PLS 12KLRX10SX15G     200      12    2400 
    ADU 24SBX200ML        200      24    4800
    NIS 18BNDX40SX11G     200      18    3600
    REF 500GX12BTL        200      12    2400
```

anyone know how to extract the numbers? thanks very much in advance

Answer (score 1):

One way using base R, is to use `sub` to extract numbers besides those groups and multiply them with `stock` to get `total`.

```
df$pcs <- as.numeric(sub(".*?(\\d+)(GUSSET|KLR|SB|BND|BTL).*", "\\1", df$item))
df$total <- df$stock * df$pcs

df
#               item stock pcs total
#PRE 24GUSSETX4SX15G   200  24  4800
#PLS   12KLRX10SX15G   200  12  2400
#ADU      24SBX200ML   200  24  4800
#NIS   18BNDX40SX11G   200  18  3600
#REF      500GX12BTL   200  12  2400
```

---

Or everything in one pipe

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(pcs = as.numeric(sub(".*?(\\d+)(GUSSET|KLR|SB|BND|BTL).*", "\\1", item)), 
         total = stock * pcs)
```

Comment: what is the difference if i did this "mutate(pcs = as.numeric(x = str_sub(string = str_extract(string = produk,pattern = "\\d+[GUSSET|KLR|SB|BND|BTL]"),start = 1,end = -2))"

Comment: @NicodemusSigitSutanto that's a different strategy I think. I am not exactly sure what it does.

Comment: i've found the answer. Thanx for the enlightment

Answer (score 0):

We can do this in `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
    mutate(pcs = as.numeric(str_extract(item, "(\\d+)(?=(GUSSET|KLR|SB|BND|BTL))")),
    total = pcs * stock)
#                 item stock pcs total
#1 PRE 24GUSSETX4SX15G   200  24  4800
#2   PLS 12KLRX10SX15G   200  12  2400
#3      ADU 24SBX200ML   200  24  4800
#4   NIS 18BNDX40SX11G   200  18  3600
#5      REF 500GX12BTL   200  12  2400
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(item = c("PRE 24GUSSETX4SX15G", "PLS 12KLRX10SX15G", 
"ADU 24SBX200ML", "NIS 18BNDX40SX11G", "REF 500GX12BTL"), stock = c(200L, 
200L, 200L, 200L, 200L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```